# compress spark output files

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

I am trying to compress spark output using below, but my output is uncompressed , any idea why?I dont have the full code here but put in whatever is required for the question .

```
           try (final JavaSparkContext context = new JavaSparkContext(sc)) 
                   {

            context.hadoopConfiguration().set("mapreduce.output.basename", prefix);
            context.hadoopConfiguration().set("mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.codec",
                    "com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzopCodec");              
 uncompressed.coalesce(count).saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(
                            output,
                            NullWritable.class,
                            Text.class,
                            TextOutputFormat.class,
                            context.hadoopConfiguration());
```

}

An i doing anything wrong here? As far as i know

```
context.hadoopConfiguration().set("mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.codec",
                    "com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzopCodec");  should do the trick.
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing             context.hadoopConfiguration().set("mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress", "true");

it works now.